# Team of 2 developers, what are the best practices?

Tags: git, repository

I have started working in a new company and currently there is me and one more developer. There are only 2 of us working on one project.

They work chaotially, just commit into dev branch everything they do. I feel more comfortable working with separate branches and merge requests, those should be code reviewed, tested and approved. The other developer just commits directly into dev branch, no code review, no nothing.

It this okay for a 2-person development team, or should i propose a more professional approach? I am working here only for one week and i dont know if i can even make such proposals?

Comment: There is no way to provide an *answer* to this, only *opinions*, and without more context, those opinions might even be based on wrong assumptions. Committing directly to master/main/dev branch can certainly be OK if you're a gründer company trying to get a head start, **as long as you acknowledge and evaluate the risks**. For a mature product/project, I would say it would definitely not be OK.

Comment: The best person/s to ask this is that *other* developer you are working with or whoever you report to. If you think you should be following some development processes (ex. code review), then discuss this with them.

Answer (score 1):

I would voice my concerns to whoever is in charge, and if he comes from a technical background he would understand that what is being done is in-correct and just makes everything chaotic, and full of bugs.

1. What i would suggest is before anyone can merge with master, the other developer has to review the pull request - review code.
2. pull request should be a reasonable sum of code not 5k + lines - Divide the code into different branches unless its an issue that needs to be fixed which takes 5k lines.
3. you could use Continuous Integration, which checks the code for bugs everytime someone does a pull request - (tests must be written)
4. Code review
5. pair-programming

as you can see the solutions are endless - you just need to find what works for both of you.

Good Luck!

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, it’s better to follow the same standards in one team. And development proposals always need to be voiced. A wise leader will listen, or maybe notice that at least you are trying.